# Controlling AutoCorrect View Position on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to control the position of the auto correct view that pops up while typing in a `UITextField`?

By default it appears to always appear below the text field. However in Apple's apps like SMS it sometimes appears above the text field.

For text fields aligned right above the keyboard the auto correct is blocked by the keyboard and not usable.

Comment: Bump! Any answers after 1 year?

Comment: technically it's not possible, and there's no public API that would allow doing this. However, one can modify the position of the correction popup: the popup is a subview of the text area, and hence can be found by iterating through the subviews. The you can find it's original position and move it wherever. Put this logic into a method and call it every time text field's "layoutSubviews" is called... I'm yet to see a cleaner solution

Answer (score 1):

The position of the auto correction prompt is determined by the firstRect... method of the UITextInput protocol. Unfortunately UITextField uses a private class as delegate for this protocol so you cannot subclass and override it.

You COULD however implement your own UITextField replacement by drawing the contents yourself (like with CoreText), implement your own selection and loupe handling and then you would be able to affect the position of the auto correction prompt. Though it's designed to always be below the edited text, so you would have to essentially lie on the firstRect ... method.

Long story short: it's too much hassle.

Answer (score 0):

One answer it worked for me is to use setInputAccessoryView method of the textview/textview. 
I have a toolbar which contains the textView.
If I set the toolbar as the inputaccessoryview of the textfield, and set to NO clipsToBound property of the toolbar, I don't know exactly why, but the balloon appears above the keyboard

Comment: Have you been able to figure out how to make it show up... above the field being edited instead of below?. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using private APIs as there are no ways to do this using public APIs.

- Hunt through the application's -windows property to find the private UITextEffectsWindow window and figure out its frame. This is the keyboard
- Hunt through the TextView's subviews to find the private UIAutocorrectInlinePrompt view. This is the autocorrect bubble.
- Move that subview into a separate wrapper view (added to the TextView) and then move that wrapper view so it's above the above-mentioned keyboard window.

Using swizzled layoutSubViews,

```
- (void) moveSpellingCorrection {
for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
{
    if ([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UIAutocorrectInlinePrompt"])
    {
        UIView *correctionShadowView = nil; // [view correctionShadowView];

        for (UIView *subview in view.subviews)
        {
            if ([[[subview class] description] isEqualToString:@"UIAutocorrectShadowView"])
            {
                correctionShadowView = subview;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (correctionShadowView)
        {
            UIView *typedTextView = nil; //[view typedTextView];
            UIView *correctionView = nil; //[view correctionView];

            for (UIView *subview in view.subviews)
            {
                if ([[[subview class] description] isEqualToString:@"UIAutocorrectTextView"])
                {
                    if (CGRectContainsRect(correctionShadowView.frame,subview.frame))
                    {
                        correctionView = subview;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        typedTextView = subview;
                    }
                }

            }
            if (correctionView && typedTextView)
            {

                CGRect textRect = [typedTextView frame];
                CGRect correctionRect = [correctionView frame];
                if (textRect.origin.y < correctionRect.origin.y)
                {
                    CGAffineTransform moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-50.0);
                    [correctionView setTransform: moveUp];
                    [correctionShadowView setTransform: moveUp];

                    CGRect windowPos = [self convertRect: view.frame toView: nil ];
                    [view removeFromSuperview];
                    [self.window addSubview: view];
                    view.frame = windowPos;
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

}

For more details [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977249/how-to-move-uitextview-correction-suggestion-above-text).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the AutoCorrect view's position is shifted because of the font's leading (line gap).

So, I tried to move it up the leading px by using firstRect function as the code below.

```
class CustomTextView: UITextView {
    override var font: UIFont? {
        didSet {
            if let font = font {
                leadingFont = font.leading
            } else {
                leadingFont = 0
            }
        }
    }
    var leadingFont: CGFloat = 0

    override func firstRect(for range: UITextRange) -> CGRect {
        var newRect = super.firstRect(for: range)
        newRect.origin = CGPoint(x: newRect.origin.x, y: newRect.origin.y - leadingFont)
        print("newRect: \(newRect)")
        return newRect
    }
}
```

Although it's UITextView but you can do the same thing with UITextField