# auto correction hidden under keyboard in iphone 6

Tags: ios, iphone

Auto correction of `UITextview` is working perfectly in Iphone5s but it is getting hidden behind the keyboard in iphone 6

works as expected in iPhone 5s

[image: works in iPhone 5s]

But does not work in iphone 6

[image]

Is there any way to fix this in iphone 6

Comment: is it 2 different view ?

Comment: No, same view, just icon changed

Comment: Have you checked with settings page .

Comment: @UmaMadhavi settings page??

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2luuo81&s=9#.VnPRBDaO5sM like this

Comment: @UmaMadhavi auto correction is enabled in the setting but the issue is bubble is getting hidden behind the keyboard

Comment: What is the layout of your view hierarchy? In particular, is the superview of your textfield just the bar above the keyboard, or does it extend below the keyboard?

Comment: Note that this only happens if the user has disabled predictive typing (swiped down on the predictive typing bar to collapse it), of course.

Comment: @jcaron No superview of uitextview doesn't extend below keyboard.

Comment: Its really use full for this issue :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977249/how-to-move-uitextview-correction-suggestion-above-text?lq=1

Comment: Did you get the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

NO , go to property and change **correction**  Default or Yes to NO

Programmatically 
Objective C:

```
[textview setSpellCheckingType:  UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo];
```

Swift :

```
 username.spellCheckingType = .No
```