# Auto correction Text hidden under keyboard in iphone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitextview

Auto correction of `UITextview` is working perfectly in `iPhone 5s` but it is not displaying proper and hidden behind the keyboard in `iPhone 6`.

I am taking reference of this:

[auto correction hidden under keyboard in iphone 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304628/auto-correction-hidden-under-keyboard-in-iphone-6?lq=1)

But i could not find any proper solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977249/how-to-move-uitextview-correction-suggestion-above-text?lq=1

Comment: I had checked this answer but it is not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue that need to handle in devices with different size and portrait to landscape switching, so you can go for a general solution for all screens.

1. Use this 3rd party library IQkeyboardManager(you can find it in github).
2. or listen keyboard show and hide notification and implement a logic to handle the keyWindow position.