# How do you prevent UITextField's autocorrect bubble from overlapping with the inputAccessoryView?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, uikit

First of all, thanks for your time in advance. I'm struggling with an annoying glitch.
I've built a quick sample project just to make sure i don't have anything around messing up with this.

As you can see, the 'autocorrect bubble' overlaps the inputAccesoryView of my UITextField.

Does anybody know if there is a way to specify that the bubble should be displayed... above the field?.

It seems to me that this is an UIKit glitch, in the routine that calculates the bubble's position. It's clearly not accounting for the inputAccesoryView.

In fact, if i remove the UIToolbar, and place the UITextField right above the keyboard, the bubble will be displayed upwards.

Any idea will be very welcome.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911323/controlling-autocorrect-view-position-on-iphone

Comment: Thanks Nicolas..!!. We're currently writing our own full TextField implementation. Using private api just to fix this sounds... to me... like a terribly bad idea.

Comment: @jorge, i think you biggest problem is your input field should be scrolled further to the top and **not** the on the edge. If there is a bit more space between your UITextView and your keyboard, it should be fine.

Comment: @Rogier thanks for your feedback!. Yes, that was the first thing i thought of. But it was a hacky solution... since it was a text editor with a predefined height. And the field that caused problems was at the very bottom of the screen. We ended up implementing our own UITextView, and... that's it, you get to really fix this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you figure out the answer to this question or not. May be it will help you and others. In text view or textfeild properties(in the right view) there is a property called "Correction". Set it to 'NONE'. It will remove autocorrection.

Comment: The idea was to keep autocorrection enabled, and fix the bubble's position. But thanks anyways!